# VBA, excel cut a part from a string

Tags: vba, excel, trim

I would like to get a part from a string. Im not familiar with VBA or unusual excel functions, but I think maybe a macro or a VBA code can help me.

I need to cut down everything from the whole string from the cell, except what is after the Total. To clear this, I need the numbers which stand after the total. I dont know any functions in excel which can solve my problem. Is there something like trim or something which recognize the 'total' and give me the number after that?

Example:
From this cell I need the 47 and the other 47

Cell: **Appvg - Total: 47 GB - Free:20 Gb; rootvg - Total: 47 -Free: <1 GB>**

Comment: Will you only be looking for the numbers after Total?   Or might you be using some other key words also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the two Totals always be the same? If so, you can use this formula (just put this in a cell on the same row as your data, I am assuming your Cell is A1):

`=TRIM(MID(A2,SEARCH("total: ",A2)+LEN("total: "),2))`

If the GB numbers will ever be larger than two digits, change the "2" to "3".  Do you have any other example cell data to work off to improve the above?

Edit: If the numbers will be different, you can use this:
`=MID(A1,SEARCH("appvg - total: ",A1)+LEN("appvg - total: "),2)&", "&MID(A1,SEARCH("rootvg - total: ",A1)+LEN("rootvg - total: "),2)`

edit 2: I am working on the formula so if the GB are greater than two digits, such as 964 GB, to have a way to dynamically pick that out.  This seems to work up to numbers 4 digits long:
`=MID(A4,SEARCH("appvg - total: ",A4)+LEN("appvg - total: "),SEARCH(" G",A4)-SEARCH(":",A4)-2)&", "&MID(A4,SEARCH("rootvg - total: ",A4)+LEN("rootvg - total: "),SEARCH(" G",A4,SEARCH(" G",A4)-SEARCH(":",A4)-1)-SEARCH(":",A4)-2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a true VBA solution, here's a function to get to at least the first number (and a similar one can be created to get to the second number):

```
Function first_number(a_string As String) As Double
    'assumes one space after each "Total:" occurrence
    loc_of_first_total = InStr(1, a_string, "Total")
    end_of_first_number = InStr(loc_of_first_total + 7, a_string, " ") - 1
    first_number = CDbl(Mid(a_string, loc_of_first_total + 7, end_of_first_number - loc_of_first_total - 6))
End Function
```

If you're not familiar with InStr, a Google search would probably get to a better explanation than I could provide. All the numbers I used (e.g., 7, 1, 6) are just the math of where the number will be if you assume that "Total:" plus one space exists before each number needed. I wasn't sure if decimals could exist, so I returned a Double, but it could be an Integer or Long depending on what you expect in the data.

Comment: I should note though that I usually always try to do a formula solution when possible, so I prefer @user3578951's answer. But if you need something quick-and-dirty, or something that can handle longer numbers and/or decimals, this could be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

For the first instance:  (where WordToFind might be "Total:"

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/MID(A1,SEARCH(WordToFind,A1)+LEN(WordToFind)+1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:5"))),MID(A1,SEARCH(WordToFind,A1)+LEN(WordToFind)+1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:5"))))
```

For the 2nd instance:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/MID(A1,SEARCH(WordToFind,A1,SEARCH(WordToFind,A1)+1)+LEN(WordToFind)+1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:5"))),MID(A1,SEARCH(WordToFind,A1,SEARCH(WordToFind,A1)+1)+LEN(WordToFind)+1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:5"))))
```

If you need more instances, VBA might be a better option.
If your number portion might be longer than 5 characters, change the "5" in "1:5"

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need the results in two separated cells.
Also note that the *key string* to search for is **"Total:"**

Cell **A11** has the following value *(use different totals as to validate the different results)*

**Appvg - Total: 147 GB - Free:20 Gb; rootvg - Total: 247 -Free: <1 GB>**

*Use this formula to obtain the Total: 147* (GB)

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A11,LEFT(A11,LEN("Total:")+SEARCH("Total:",A11)),""),
-1+SEARCH(" ",SUBSTITUTE(A11,LEFT(A11,LEN("Total:")+SEARCH("Total:",A11)),"")))
```

*Use this formula to obtain the Total: 247* (-Free)

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A11,LEFT(A11,
LEN("Total:")+SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(A11,"Total:","|",2))),""),
-1+SEARCH(" ",SUBSTITUTE(A11,
LEFT(A11,LEN("Total:")+SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(A11,"Total:","|",2))),"")))
```

In case the *key string* changes, a cell can be use to enter the *key strings* to search. If this is the case use these formulas:

The *key string* **"Total:"** is entered in cell **A12**

*Use this formula to obtain the Total: 147* (GB)

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A11,LEFT(A11,LEN(A12)+SEARCH(A12,A11)),""),
-1+SEARCH(" ",SUBSTITUTE(A11,LEFT(A11,LEN(A12)+SEARCH(A12,A11)),"")))
```

*Use this formula to obtain the Total: 247* (-Free)

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A11,LEFT(A11,
LEN(A12)+SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(A11,A12,"|",2))),""),
-1+SEARCH(" ",SUBSTITUTE(A11,LEFT(A11,
LEN(A12)+SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(A11,A12,"|",2))),"")))
```

All formulas work regardless of the length of the numbers